# vbscript control loop structure works on one windows 10 desktop and not on another windows 10 laptop. What could be wrong?

Tags: vbscript

I have following vbscript code segment that works fine on one windows 10 desktop but not on another windows 10 laptop.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

dim r, i, j
randomize

For j = 1 To 5
For i = 1 To 5
  r = Int(rnd*1000) + 3400
  strMsg = "Loop = " + CStr(j) + " / " + CStr(i) + vbNewLine + "delay = " + CStr(r)  
  strI = " Loop " + CStr(j) + " / " + CStr(i)
  WshShell.Popup strMsg, 13, strI 
  Wscript.Sleep(r)
Next

Next
```

On Desktop, it works fine, meaning I get all message popup's with correct content.  I do see wscript process in Task Manager Details tab while this code is executing.

On laptop, I get only first popup with correct value.  Control does not iterate through other values of i and j.  Here too, I see wscript process in Task Manager Details tab only for brief period of time i.e. during first iteration and while first popup is closed after about 13 seconds..

What could be wrong?
could it be cscript vs wscript thing?

Thanks.

Comment: could be that it is doing a really long sleep and that it is working. what if you comment out the random sleep one? I mean, if it works, the random could be minutes, even hours.

Comment: It seems it is not sleeping or waiting as I can see wscript process entry come and go in details tab of Task Manager window.  I see wscript entry when I start vbs script and soon after it disappears.